# Script/Style getting cached in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a personal project in Visual Studio 2010 Express edition, using ASP.NET & C#.

When i debug my web pages, for some reason a few of my css & script files don't reflect the changes i've made to them. When i check their content using firebug, i see it's the old un-modified content, as if a cached copy was used instead of the new changed one. This doesn't happen with all the files, only a few.

I tried restarting visual studio, deleting and adding the style/script again, but to no avail. I still see the old copies instead of the new ones.

Any idea what wold be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local browser cache is probably the reason - did you try loading the page/s with a hard reload (<kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd>)?

Comment: Jeez, feel like a doofus right now. /facepalm
It's the correct answer btw. Thanks.